# Discord.py How can I create a channel with the nickname of user who clicked the emoji in message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
    self.ticket_creator = user_id

    message = await channel.fetch_message(message_id)
    await message.remove_reaction("",user)


ticket_nr = random.randint(100,999)
self.channel_ticket = await category.create_text_channel(f'bilet-{ticket_nr}', 
overwrites=overwrites)
```

Here, when a user clicks on the emoji, it deletes the emoji and creates a text channel whose title consists of random numbers.How can i make the discord nickname of user who clicked the emoji instead of these random numbers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `self.channel_ticket = await category.create_text_channel(f'bilet-{ticket_nr}',  overwrites=overwrites)` to `self.channel_ticket = await category.create_text_channel(user.name,  overwrites=overwrites)`. This should do what you want.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'username'` it gives this error

Comment: My bad, I got the attribute wrong. Updated the post.

Comment: After creating this channel, how can I send a dm to the creator as this channel has been created?